# How do I show the % completed with ng-bootstrap NgbProgressBar?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a 5 to 15 seconds initialization operation in my angular app, and want to use [NgbProgressBar](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar) to show the progress in %. Currently I use [Angular Http](https://angular.io/guide/http) provider functions to retrieve the data which is a single call operation does not help to get the % done.

How can the Browser know the % completed using [Http service](https://angular.io/guide/http), and update the `NgbProgressBar`? Is there a different JavaScript framework that I can use to achieve this if I can't do with [http](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. Neither your Angular app nor the browser knows how much data needs to be retrieved, so it wouldn't be able to calculate a percentage. You need some hook that you can tie into and asynchronously update your progress bar. Now, if you know the upper limits of the payload size, I guess you could spoof the progress by just adding X percent every Y seconds, assuming your http call is non-blocking.